# Angular 6 kendo-dropdownlist conditionally set [valueField] and [textField]

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, conditional-statements, textfield

I have a kendo-dropdownlist in Angular 6 project, which needs to populate from two different datasets based on a condition. I am having difficulty in figuring out how to set the [valueField] and [textField] based on condition

```
   <kendo-dropdownlist id="UP_CM_IN" name="UP_CM_IN"
            style="width:90%"
            [(ngModel)]="SelectUP_CM_IN"
            [defaultItem]="defaultUP_CM_IN"
            [data]="UP_CM_IN"
            [filterable]="true"
            *ngIf="selectedCS=='CM' ? [valueField]='CD_IN': [valueField]='UP_IN'"
            *ngIf="selectedCS=='CM' ? [textField]='CD_IN': [textField]='UP_IN'"
            (valueChange)="handleUP_CM_INChange($event)"
            (filterChange)="handleUP_CM_INFilter($event)">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it might not possible to change just the data set conditionally..
 but what you can do is... Create 2 drop down elements with different dataset and show them on Dom conditionally with *ngIf directive...

Example:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="selectedCS=='CM'" id="UP_CM_IN" name="UP_CM_IN"
            style="width:90%"
            [(ngModel)]="SelectUP_CM_IN"
            [defaultItem]="defaultUP_CM_IN"
            [data]="UP_CM_IN"
            [filterable]="true"
            [valueField]='CD_IN': 
            [textField]='UP_IN'"
            (valueChange)="handleUP_CM_INChange($event)"
            (filterChange)="handleUP_CM_INFilter($event)">
</kendo-dropdownlist>

<kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="selectedCS!='CM'" id="UP_CM_IN" name="UP_CM_IN"
            style="width:90%"
            [(ngModel)]="SelectUP_CM_IN"
            [defaultItem]="defaultUP_CM_IN"
            [data]="UP_CM_IN"
            [valueField]='CD_IN': 
            [textField]='UP_IN'"
            [filterable]="true"
            (valueChange)="handleUP_CM_INChange($event)"
            (filterChange)="handleUP_CM_INFilter($event)">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```